# c# List act as Mock<DbDataReader>

Tags: c#, mocking

I have complicated validation during reading data from DbDataReader so i want to test the validation implementation with unit tests. In order to do that i want to create a list with test data and just transform it to DbDataReader and mock the object, but currently without success. I've tried several things like this :

```
        foreach (var record in lRecords)
        {
            moq.Setup(x => x["batch_number"])
            .Returns(() => lRecords[counterStartingAtOne].batch_number);
        }
```

But i don't have generic solution , to work without hardcoding the field names and so on.

Comment: Have you tried this package: [Moq.DataReader](https://github.com/verdie-g/Moq.DataReader)?

Comment: looks promising, i will give it a try , that's for sure - thank you !